# RecyclerView gets IndexOutOfBoundsException when scrolling (Retrofit + Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit

Im getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when i'm inside a recyclerview and scroll up and down for a while.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar, PID: 15457
>                                                                                      java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>                                                                                          at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>                                                                                          at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar.MapListActivity$1$1.onResponse(MapListActivity.java:84)
>                                                                                          at
>   retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

The code look like this

```
 mRecycleViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyLatLng, LatLngViewHolder>(MyLatLng.class, R.layout.list_item, LatLngViewHolder.class, ref) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final LatLngViewHolder latLngViewHolder, MyLatLng myLatLng, final int i) {


                List<String> latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Waypoints> waypoint : myLatLng.getWaypoints().entrySet()) {
                    // String key = waypoint.getKey();
                    Waypoints value = waypoint.getValue();
                    String waypointsMsg = value.getLatitude() + ", " + value.getLongitude();
                    latLngList.add(waypointsMsg);
                }
                String startLatLng = latLngList.get(0);
                String endLatLng = latLngList.get(latLngList.size() - 1);


                RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
                Call<Direction> call = restClient.getApiService().getDirectionsWithLatLng(startLatLng, endLatLng);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Direction>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Direction> call, Response<Direction> response) {


                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                            Direction direction = response.body();

                            String distance = direction.getRoutes().get(0).getLegs().get(0).getDistance().getText();
                            latLngViewHolder.kmLength.setText(distance);
                            String locationA = direction.getRoutes().get(0).getLegs().get(0).getStartAddress();
                            latLngViewHolder.locationA.setText(locationA);
                            String locationB = direction.getRoutes().get(0).getLegs().get(0).getEndAddress();
                            latLngViewHolder.locationB.setText(locationB);


                            latLngViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "You clicked on " + i);

                                    String mainKey = mRecycleViewAdapter.getRef(i).getKey();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("firebaseKey_from_clicked_list_item", mainKey);
                                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                                }
                            });

                        } else {

                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error message");
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Direction> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }

        };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecycleViewAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Your `distance`, `locationA`, and/or `locationB` instantiations are making a lot of assumptions that the lists aren't empty. You need to check that getRoutes() and getLegs() exists and have a size() > 0 before you attempt to utilize them like this.

Comment: As @zgc7009 says, the problem is not related with the RecyclerView. If you read carefully you'll see how the problem is in the onResponse method.

Comment: Thanks for the help.